# Google Analytics Polymer Web Components - Safari Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-analytics, datepicker, polymer

I am using [Google's Polymer Analytics Web Components](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-analytics) to build a dashboard. However, these elements seem to rely on HTML 5 (great in most cases), but with Safari (Mac), their is no native HTML 5 datepicker.

How does one go about binding JqueryUI Datpicker (or equivalent) to these components?

for example:

```
 <google-analytics-date-selector></google-analytics-date-selector>
```

creates the following shadow code block:

```
<google-analytics-date-selector class="x-scope google-analytics-date-selector-0">
  <span class="control style-scope google-analytics-date-selector">
    <label for="startDate" class="style-scope google-analytics-date-selector">Start Date</label>
    <input id="startDate" type="date" class="style-scope google-analytics-date-selector hasDatepicker" max="2016-03-30" min="2005-01-01">
  </span>
  <span class="control style-scope google-analytics-date-selector">
    <label for="endDate" class="style-scope google-analytics-date-selector">End Date</label>
    <input id="endDate" type="date" class="style-scope google-analytics-date-selector" min="2016-03-24" max="2016-03-31">
  </span>
</google-analytics-date-selector>
```

How can I target the `#startDate` and `#endDate` input elements with JQUI Datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`<paper-date-picker>`](http://bendavis78.github.io/paper-date-picker/paper-date-picker/), which works in multiple browsers, including Safari -- or pick one of the other date pickers from [exploring Custom Elements](https://customelements.io/search/datepicker).

The `<paper-date-picker>` docs show an example snippet:

```
<paper-dialog class="paper-date-picker-dialog" modal>
  <paper-date-picker date="[[date]]"></paper-date-picker>
  <div class="buttons">
    <paper-button dialog-dismiss>Cancel</paper-button>
    <paper-button dialog-confirm>OK</paper-button>
  </div>
</paper-dialog>
```

which creates a modal dialog, containing the date-picker, as seen in this Safari screenshot:

[image: paper-date-picker in Safari]